# RootLayoutPanel:- fetch specific content

Tags: gwt, layout

Please help in understanding this.

I want to access specific content on my page. If am using RootLayoutPanel in my view, how can I access specific content using get()?

If its not possible why is it so?

Thanks.

Comment: I mistaken that its RootPanel.

Comment: I don't understand. Please clarify a bit.